# How to Upload video on Vimeo with name/title using .net core api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, vimeo

I am using the following code to upload video on Vimeo. I want to add filename as video title currently I am getting Untitled video with the above code
please guide me how to add Title/Name

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadVideos([FromForm] IFormFile videoFile)
    {
        string tagName = "tagName";            

        //var files = Request.Form.Files;
        //IFormFile file = files[0];
        string uploadStatus = "";
        var getVideo = new Video();
        try
        {
            if (videoFile != null)
            {
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                VimeoClient vimeoClient = new VimeoClient(accessToken);
                var authcheck = await vimeoClient.GetAccountInformationAsync();

                if (authcheck.Name != null)
                {
                    IUploadRequest uploadRequest = new UploadRequest();
                    //Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();
                    //using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    //{
                    //    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    //    memoryStream.ToArray();
                    //}
                    BinaryContent binaryContent = new BinaryContent(obj.videoFile.OpenReadStream(), obj.videoFile.ContentType);
                    int chunkSize = 0;
                    int contentLength = Convert.ToInt32(obj.videoFile.Length);
                    int temp1 = contentLength / 1024;
                    binaryContent.OriginalFileName = "Test Name";
                    if (temp1 > 1)
                    {
                        chunkSize = temp1 / 1024;
                        if (chunkSize == 0)
                        {
                            chunkSize = 1048576;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (chunkSize > 10)
                            {
                                chunkSize = chunkSize / 10;
                            }
                            chunkSize = chunkSize * 1048576;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chunkSize = 1048576;
                    }
                    var checkChunk = chunkSize;
                    var status = "uploading";
                    uploadRequest = await vimeoClient.UploadEntireFileAsync(binaryContent, chunkSize, null);
                    var _tag =  tagName;
                    var tagVideo = await vimeoClient.AddVideoTagAsync(uploadRequest.ClipId.GetValueOrDefault(), _tag);
                    while (status != "available")
                    {
                        getVideo = await vimeoClient.GetVideoAsync(long.Parse(uploadRequest.ClipId.Value.ToString()));
                        status = getVideo.Status;
                    }
                    uploadStatus = String.Concat("file Uploaded ", getVideo.Files[0].LinkSecure);
                }
            }
            return Ok(new { status = uploadStatus, video = getVideo });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I tried to set title with this binaryContent.OriginalFileName but its results untitled video. Please guide by providing the modification required in the api

Answer (score 0):

I try to refer to the Vimeo documentation and come to know that you could use the Pull approach or you could set metadata for the video to set the title.

Video uploads on Vimeo include metadata such as the name of the video and the video's privacy settings. Besides being useful as titles and text descriptors, metadata are also a key component in strategies for search engine optimization.
You can specify values for a video's metadata fields in the body of the initial POST request of an upload, like this:

```
{
  "upload": {
    "approach": "tus",
    "size": 800000000
  },
  "name": "My Video",
  "privacy": { "view": "nobody" }
}
```

- If you don’t specify a name for your video, we automatically give it the name Untitled, unless you upload it with the pull approach. In that case, we use the file name of the video.

For more detailed information, please refer to **Setting video metadata** point in [this document](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos).